# Term to describe a subgraph of a digraph where no arcs go into it from outside

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, directed-graphs

What's the shortest way to describe a subgraph of a digraph where, in the original graph, no arcs go into it from outside? Is there a term for this?

Note that it might or might not be connected.

Here's an example:

[image]

A real life example is an intranet. It can have hyperlinks to the WWW, but the WWW won't have hyperlinks to it.

Comment: I suggest a source subgraph, because a source is a node with no incoming edge.

Comment: I like that! I was also thinking 'unreachable subgraph', but that seems ambiguous on where it's unreachable from.

Comment: Found 'source subgraph' used here: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC8260706/ -- "A subgraph Γ is called a source subgraph of G if there is no edge from G\Γ to Γ.".

If you'd like to submit your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest a source subgraph, because a source is a node with no incoming edge.